# How to detect click on ImageView in ViewPager's PagerAdapter (android)?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-imageview, android-pageradapter

**What is happening:**

1. i am trying to detect a onclick event for a view(image) in pager
   adapter.
2. View i am triggering is `imgGodInfoId`
3. This is never triggered
4. This seems to work in regular adapter ... so why is it not triggered
   here

**AdptAtomicGodGallery.java**

```
public class AdptAtomicGodGallery extends PagerAdapter {
    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    Integer[] godImages;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String godName;


    public AdptAtomicGodGallery(Context context, Integer[] _godImages, String _godName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.godImages = _godImages;
        this.godName=_godName;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return godImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        // Declare Variables
        ImageView imgGodId;
        final ImageView imgGodInfoId;
        final RelativeLayout root;
        TextView txtShortDescription;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_atomic_god_gallery, container,false);

        // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
        imgGodId = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgGodId);
        imgGodInfoId = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgGodInfoId);
        root= (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        txtShortDescription= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtShortDescription);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),godImages[position], options);
        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),preview_bitmap);
        root.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        root.setTag(godImages[position]);
        imgGodInfoId.setTag(godName);


        if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_ONE)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_ONE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_TWO)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_TWO_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_THREE)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_THREE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_FOUR)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_FOUR_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_FIVE)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_FIVE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_SIX)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_SIX_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_SEVEN)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_SEVEN_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_EIGHT)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_EIGHT_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_NINE)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_NINE_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }else if(godName.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.GOD_TEN)){
            txtShortDescription.setText(Constants.GOD_TEN_DESCRIPTION_SHORT_DESC);
        }



        imgGodInfoId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                /*  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 4;
                Bitmap preview_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),(Integer) root.getTag(), options);

                 */

                Toast.makeText(context, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /*Intent intent=new Intent(context,ActAtomicGodDetailDesc.class);
                intent.putExtra("GOD_NAME", imgGodInfoId.getTag().toString());
                intent.putExtra("GOD_IMAGE",(Integer) root.getTag());
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intent);*/

            }
        });


        // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);



        return itemView;
    }




    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((LinearLayout) object);

    }
}
```

**Xml for pager adapter**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgGodInfoId"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/img_info_black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selShortDescContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/sel_selectyourgod"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtShortDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/swipe_notification"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:color="#55000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selFavGodsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selShortDescContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="141dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sel_selectyourgod"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNotification"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/swipe_notification"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:color="#55000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added `android:clickable="true"` in xml for ImageView?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK ... Yes i tried that ... still the toast in the code is not fired

Comment: parent view of ImageView is click-able or not?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K  .... yes parent is also clickable ......... but have i used proper code to detect onclick ... because i have never tried to detect onclick in pager adapter ,,,, it seemed to work for regular listview ... this logic

Comment: `root` layout is also click-able ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK .... i have posted the xml of adapter too .. please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71382/discussion-between-devrath-and--k).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to do it this way: override the `onViewCreated()` method of the `Fragment`s held by your `ViewPager` as:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            /*  Do as you please here. */
        }
    });
}
```

Try this. This should work.

**EDIT:**

This approach will work provided you use a `ViewPager` and `PagerAdapter` with `Fragment`s, and override the `onViewCreated()` method of the `Fragment`s.

Comment: Should i need to add any super method here ... what is it ... i get a error as ....... `The method onViewCreated(View, Bundle) of type AdptAtomicGodGallery must override or implement a supertype method`

Comment: Clean and build your project again. `onViewCreated()` *is* a supertype method.

Comment: for i/p [+1]....Also since i am using activity should i need to use this function in activity ?

Comment: `Activity` doesn't have this method. This is strictly for the `Fragment`s held by your `PagerAdapter` :)

Comment: Oh .... i was using activity .... i am really surprised this is not possible in pager adaper since its so easy to do in a listview

Comment: :( ... Since i am using activity, i am not able to do this ..... i tried to do onclick as i have posted in ques ... still not havin a workaround for this

Comment: Your `PagerAdapter` is holding a collection of `Fragment`s, right ?

Comment: If you use a `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, and make use of `Fragment`s instead of `ImageView`s, then the above solution will work. I thought you were using `Fragment`s all along ... `onViewCreated()` is a virtual method of `Fragment` :)

Comment: @Devrath: where have you reached so far ?

Comment: I found a workaround for this use case by removing that option .... But thanks for the info