# OnClick Listener is not triggered inside a fragment with View Pager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I'd like to be able to set a `View.OnclickListener` to an `ImageView` inside a page (fragment) of my `ViewPager`, I don't want to click on the whole page of my `ViewPager`, I just want to be able to click on a specifig `ImageView`. I followed these questions ([onClick not triggered on LinearLayout with child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763876/onclick-not-triggered-on-linearlayout-with-child), [How to set OnClickListener in ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350987/viewpager-onitemclicklistener)
) but they did not help me. This is my actual code:

MyPageFragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/container_linear"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/product_view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="240dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

MyFragment.class (where I'm binding the views using Butterknife)

```
@BindView(R.id.container_linear)
LinearLayout mContainer;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);

    mContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Test", "Clicked!");
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using the following chunk of code:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){

            /*  Do as you please here. */
        }
    });
}
```

The reference for this answer can be viewed here: [How to detect click on ImageView in ViewPager's PagerAdapter (android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645740/how-to-detect-click-on-imageview-in-viewpagers-pageradapter-android)

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider would be moving your OnClickListener to the parent LinearLayout you're setting as clickable and seeing if that helps.

Another thing is adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the view you're attaching your OnClickListener to.

Other than that, you might want to share the code for registering the OnClickListener so we can investigate other possible errors.

Comment: thanks, I just implemented what you suggested and updated my description

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to click on the image view inside`MyPageFragment.xml`. This is simple but you need to give `ID` to the `ImageView` and refer it in your `onCreateView` method like you do for `LinearLayout` and then use `onClickListener` on that image.

> So with recent conversation it seems that in linear layout you need to **remove** line `clickable="false"`
>
> Basically that has blocked all the clicks on its children, thus that linear layout as well as the imageview clicks are not working for you. See this code I removed that line. Hope this works

Follow this code.

MyPageFragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:duplicateParentState="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/container_linear"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  
    <--you need to give ID to the view to be able to 
                         perform events on them specifically.-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your MyFragment.class

```
@BindView(R.id.container_linear)
LinearLayout mContainer;
//declare with butterknife
@BindView(R.id.my_awesome_image)
ImageView myAwesomeImage;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                     @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);
    
     //you set click listener previously on entire linear layout instead of imageview 
     //that's why it was not reflecting on imageview click.


    myAwesomeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG , "Awesome Imageview clicked!");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed my code as @Bjelis suggested. This approach using an ImageView with OnClickListener was my first choice.

Comment: not actually, I'm still not able to trigger onClickListener using those LinearLayout or ImageView

Comment: did u give ID to imageview and refered it inside fragment with correct ID ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure about that because I'm using Butterknife and if there this lib doesnt find the declared view it throws an error and the app crashes.

Comment: I implemented those changes in my code and it is not working. I implemented OnTouchListener and it worked in ImageView. But I don't want to use this approach because I am using this fragment inside a ViewPager.

Comment: actually I removed it long time ago, I'm gonna edit my question